# Using deeply nested object from JSON in AngularJS - strange behavior

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, promise, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to understand how AngularJS sees an object from a deeply nested JSON. [Here's an example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQFnQm). The data comes from service and is assigned to `$scope.data`. The javascript code seems to want me to declare every level of the object first before usage, but referencing a deep level within object from the view HTML always works, and using the deep level in a function kinda works. It's rather inconsistent.

I'm not sure if my understanding of `$scope` is lacking, or if this has something to do with promise objects. Advise please?

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Referencing nested obj in view works:
  {{data.level1.level2}}
  <br>
  Using nested obj within declared scope var doesn't work:
  {{nestedObj}}
  <br>
  Using nested obj in a function works but throws TypeError:
  {{getLen()}}
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('JsonSvc', function ($http) {
  return {read: function(jsonURL, scope) {
        $http.get(jsonURL).success(function (data, status) {
            scope.data = data;
        });
    }};
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, JsonSvc) {
    JsonSvc.read('data.json', $scope);

    // Using nested obj within declared scope var doesn't work
    // Uncomment below to break whole app
    // $scope.nestedObj = $scope.data.level1.level2;

    // Using nested obj in a function works but throws TypeError
    // Declaring $scope.data.level1.level2 = [] first helps here
    $scope.getLen = function () {return $scope.data.level1.level2.length};
});
```

JSON

```
{
    "level1": {
        "level2": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `$http` request is asynchronous.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, JsonSvc) {
    JsonSvc.read('data.json', $scope);

    //$scope.data.level1.level2 doesn't exist yet at this point in time 
    //and throws an exception
    $scope.nestedObj = $scope.data.level1.level2;

    //$scope.data.level1.level2 doesn't exist yet at this point in time 
    //and throws an exception
    //once Angular does dirty checking this one will work since the 
    //$http request finished.
    $scope.getLen = function () {
        return $scope.data.level1.level2.length
    };
});
```

Since you have three scope objects that rely on that data it would be best to assign those in the call back.

```
app.factory('JsonSvc', function ($http) {
  return {read: function(jsonURL, scope) {
        $http.get(jsonURL).success(function (data, status) {
            scope.data = data;
      scope.nestedObj = scope.data.level1.level2;
      scope.getLen = function () {
        return scope.data.level1.level2.length;
      };
        });
    }};
});
```

If you do not want to set it all up on the call back, you could also use [`$broadcast()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24broadcast) and [`$on()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24on)

```
app.factory('JsonSvc', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    return {
        read: function (jsonURL, scope) {
            $http.get(jsonURL).success(function (data, status) {
                scope.data = data;
                $rootScope.$broadcast("jsonDone");
            });
        }
    };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, JsonSvc) {
    JsonSvc.read('data.json', $scope);
    $scope.name = "world";
    $scope.$on("jsonDone", function () {
        $scope.nestedObj = $scope.data.level1.level2;
        $scope.getLen = function () {
            return $scope.data.level1.level2.length;
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I see how `$http` request is not finished. But how can I map JSON object to `$scope.data` exactly once it's finished? I thought `.success` would take care of it but apparently not. If the JSON is large with many levels, will each level have to be mapped manually and separately?

Answer (score 3):

Ray, another option is to return the $http.get call since its a promise and use the .then() function to declare $scope.nestedObj or anything else you want to do with data once it returns.

Here's my example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/GbTfJ9

You can read more about promises in Angular here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)